# R purrr with drop_na

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to use drop_na() with purrr but can't seem to get it to work.

```
 models = data %>%
     drop_na(mme) %>%
     split(.$id) %>%
     map(~lm(mme~time,data=.))

Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

I know there are NA's in mme and none in time.

Comment: Your error is telling you that you have nothing but `NA` cases in your model somewhere . You can't do much of a prediction without any valid data. E.g., I can summon the same error doing: `y <- 1:10; x <- rep(NA,10); lm(y ~ x)`

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput`?

Comment: The error comes from some certain groups that have only 1 or 2 data points all of which which are NA. I thought doing drop_na() would drop these cases though?

Comment: @Nitro - try `split(.$id, drop=TRUE)` - if `id` is a `factor`, you get splits with no data in them - e.g. - `split(1:10,factor(rep(1,10),levels=1:2))`